# Xamarin.Forms UWP Button renderer CornerRadius

Tags: button, xamarin.uwp, cornerradius

The BorderRadius property has been deprecated.  The new CorderRadius does not exists in FormsButton in Xamarin.Forms UWP Button Renderer.

Using the the deprecated BorderRadius property causes the app to crash.

Control.BorderRadius = Element.CornerRadius; (inside OnElementPropertyChanged)

I am using Xamarin 3.0.0.446417 on VS 15.7.1

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> The `BorderRadius` property has been deprecated.

[`BorderRadius`](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UAP/FormsButton.cs#L30) is [`FormsButton`](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UAP/FormsButton.cs#L8) property where under `Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP` namespace, and it has not be deprecated. And it is an extension property base on UWP `Button` class for rendering corner.

[`CornerRadius`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.button.cornerradius?view=xamarin-forms#Xamarin_Forms_Button_CornerRadius) is `Button` property where under [`Xamarin.Forms`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms?view=xamarin-forms)namespace. And it is cross-platform property that you could rendered in other platform.

You have no need to reset `BorderRadius` in the custom button render, you could use the following directly.

`<Button BorderRadius="15" Text="Click"/>`

Because it has been used in the [ButtonRenderer](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UAP/ButtonRenderer.cs#L140).

Comment: In my own custom renderer, it has the usual

protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
  base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);
}

When I run my app, the following error occurs:

An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UAP.dll but was not handled in user code

Invalid value for TopLeft property on CornerRadius.

Comment: The issue is found.  The CornerRadius has a negative value. if (e.PropertyName == "CornerRadius")
        {
          if (Element.CornerRadius >= 0)
          {
            base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);
          }
        }

Comment: You could post your answer here or update my answer and add your updates then accept to convenient people who visit this thread later, Thanks for understanding.

Answer (score 0):

The CornerRadius has a negative value that causes the app to crash.

```
protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{

    if (e.PropertyName == "CornerRadius")
    {

        if (Element.CornerRadius >= 0)
        {
            base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);
        }
    }

}
```